# how to reuse a svg element and resize

Tags: svg

I have a rectangle

`<rect id="greenRect" fill="lightgreen" height="20" width="20"/>`

Now I want to reuse the rect, but make it bigger

`<use href="#greenRect" y="150" height="50" width="50"/>`

The size (height/width) don't seem to get overwritten from the original `<rect>` element.

How would I achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Wrap the rect in a `<symbol>` with a `viewBox` attribute.

```
<symbol id="greenRect" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <rect fill="lightgreen" height="20" width="20"/>
</symbol>
<!-- symbols are not rendered, so if you want to see your original,
     you have to also use it -->
<use href="#greenRect" height="20" width="20"/>
<use href="#greenRect" y="150" height="50" width="50"/>
```

**Solution 2:** scale and translate your rectangle

```
<rect id="greenRect" fill="lightgreen" height="20" width="20"/>
<!-- transformation are applied right-to-left -->
<use href="#greenRect" transform="translate(0 150) scale(2.5)"/>
```

Comment: I especially like the symbol approach. Thanks!